# Cannot Create Table in SQL with CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a new table in SQL developer. I need to have a CHECK constraint on for Clinic_City, however it will not work. Can anybody help me?

```
CREATE TABLE TravelClinics (Clinic_Number number(3) PRIMARY KEY,
Clinic_Street varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Clinic_City varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
Clinic_County varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Postcode varchar2(7) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Tel varchar2(11) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Fax varchar2(11) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT
CHECK(Clinic_City IN ('LONDON', 'BIRMINGHAM', 'MANCHESTER', 'LEEDS', 'GLASGOW', 'EDINBURGH')))
```

Comment: Maybe consider creating a table containing valid cities and use a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint instead. This also means that adding a new city is a data operation rather than having to change the `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: Are you using MYSQL or Oracle because in MYSQL Check constraint is not there and in Oracle it is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you need to attach the constraint to the proper column, and give it a name, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TravelClinics (
    Clinic_Number number(3) PRIMARY KEY
,   Clinic_Street varchar2(20) NOT NULL
,   Clinic_City varchar2(10) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT Valid_City
        CHECK(Clinic_City IN ('LONDON', 'BIRMINGHAM', 'MANCHESTER', 'LEEDS', 'GLASGOW', 'EDINBURGH'))
,   Clinic_County varchar2(15) NOT NULL
,   Clinic_Postcode varchar2(7) NOT NULL
,   Clinic_Tel varchar2(11) NOT NULL
,   Clinic_Fax varchar2(11) NOT NULL
)
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdbaf)

A better approach would be creating a separate table for cities, inserting six rows into it, and referencing that table from your `TravelClinics` table. This would reduce the amount of information that needs to be duplicated. It would also immensely simplify adding new cities, because it would be a data operation, rather than a schema operation.

Comment: That's one way of doing it but you don't have to. Table constraints work fine in Oracle (the OP was missing a comma)

Comment: @ypercube Right, I've seen it done both ways. I prefer this one because it brings the constraint closer to the column itself, but indeed the placement  can be changed. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You are missing comma after defining `Clinic_Fax` column

```
CREATE TABLE TravelClinics (Clinic_Number number(3) PRIMARY KEY,
Clinic_Street varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Clinic_City varchar2(10) NOT NULL,
Clinic_County varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Postcode varchar2(7) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Tel varchar2(11) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Fax varchar2(11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk CHECK(Clinic_City IN ('LONDON', 'BIRMINGHAM', 'MANCHESTER', 'LEEDS', 'GLASGOW', 'EDINBURGH')))
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df36c)

Answer (score 0):

Instead create a domain table CITY and a FK to it.
If anytime you want to add a city just add a row.
The FK ill act as a constraint.

It also adds the advantage of normalization.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE TravelClinics (Clinic_Number number(3) PRIMARY KEY,
Clinic_Street varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
Clinic_City varchar2(10) constraint tc_clinic_city_nn NOT NULL CONSTRAINT tc_clinic_city_ck
CHECK(Clinic_City IN ('LONDON', 'BIRMINGHAM', 'MANCHESTER', 'LEEDS', 'GLASGOW', 'EDINBURGH')),
Clinic_County varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Postcode varchar2(7) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Tel varchar2(11) NOT NULL,
Clinic_Fax varchar2(11) NOT NULL)